# how to create download as excel option of views.py in django

Tags: django, excel, python-2.7, csv

I want to add in my django app's views.py option of 'download as excel'. The HttpResponse is in html file. Here is few views.py seem like this

```
def auto_run_html(request):
  htmlfile = HttpResponse()
  Month_no = request.GET['Month']
  htmlfile.write('<html><HEAD><LINK href="/static/timesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></HEAD>')
  htmlfile.write('<body>')
  htmlfile.write('''<table class = "Emp_Details" >
                                    <tr style="text-align:left">
                                        <th>{}</th><th>{}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="text-align:left">
                                        <th>{}</th><th>{}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="text-align:left">
                                        <th>{}</th><th>{}</th>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>'''.format('Department',dept_row,'Employee ID',dept_row[2],'Employee Name',dept_row))
  return HttpResponse(htmlfile)
```

Here I want to add download as excel operation. I have tried this as outputting csv,but it only for display as csv file instead of html in browser.The documents telling that user can save as csv file but it only give option of html page.

I am using django 1.6 & python 2.7 . This may be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187989/excel-in-django) .

I am new to python if it can only be done by python-excel procedure, then please give example with reference of my above code. Thank in advance.

Here is my csv coded veiws.py.Please mark out where am I doing wrong.

```
def auto_run_html(request):
  response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
  htmlfile = csv.writer(response)
  htmlfile.writerow('''<table class = "Emp_Details" >
                                <tr style="text-align:left">
                                    <th>{}</th><th>{}</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="text-align:left">
                                    <th>{}</th><th>{}</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="text-align:left">
                                    <th>{}</th><th>{}</th>
                                </tr>
                        </table>'''.format('Department',dept_row,'Employee ID',dept_row[2],'Employee Name',dept_row))
  return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is the way to go. You just need to properly specify content type and disposition. For example:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="document.csv"'
```

and then form actual CSV using standard python `csv` module.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I said I tried this. But this is for displaying csv in browser.

Comment: How user can download document.csv. I need to know how to download document.csv as it is not store in server

Comment: this code is correct. A well-behaved browser should not display the file contents but should prompt to download it.

Comment: I have opened it in google chrom. & I want to tell you that I have return response. So if I will create download link & assign action to document.csv, will it work..

Comment: @user2956480 sorry, I don't understand. Does it work in Chrome? What about other browsers?

Comment: Same problem. Can you please suggest me how to create download option.. May be I am doing wrong as I am returning response.

Comment: `return HttpResponse(htmlfile)` - it looks like a bug BTW. You are creating `HttpResponse` with another `HttpResponse`. Maybe it gets treated as a string and you loose your header information.

Comment: To me the problem is content_type should be 'application/csv'

Comment: @Alvaro MIME type of the CSV is text/csv according to RFC 4180. If some browser don't understand it it's actually another issue.

Comment: Why you are putting html to your csv response body?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited wrongly.. But I have write it properly for csv in my code.

Comment: BTW I got result. I did not restart the server. After restarting its downloading. Thanks a lot for you help..

Comment: @vbo I got a problem. Can You plz help me out....
When I am trying to download it in ubuntu Chromium web Browser(may be chrom for linux), it's downloading plain text format file with csv style.